# Gulp HTML and JS concatenation - ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, minify

I'm using some standard gulp processes to minify my html, css and javascript. The problem I have at the moment is that i'm concatenating and uglifying my JS into one clean scripts.js file. The distribution folder still points to multiple JS files, for example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mock-data-live.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vibrant.min.js></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="siema.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.min.js"></script>
```

Becomes

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way I can change my original paths in HTML when minifying so they all point to the one concatenated file?

Thank you

Comment: As the HTML file itself is mostly static and doesn't require rebuilding on change, why don't you statically point the script source to the final script's path `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: Heya, good point and I did think about this - part of my gulp build at the moment is minifying the HTML as well as the JS, so it gets outputted as part of the process each time I run the default gulp script.

Comment: I see. using a gulp plugin like in my example below should do the trick. And just a short remark `type="text/javascript"` can be removed as this would be the default for all script tags.

Comment: So did you find a solution? If so, could you share it?

Comment: Whoopsie, missed that - yours was the best answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem and glad you found a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install gulp-html-replace**

You will need an additional Gulp package for this: [`gulp-html-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace).

Install it via:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-html-replace
```

**Change HTML file contents**

Inside your HMTL file (assuming its called "index.html"), you would use:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- build:js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mock-data-live.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vibrant.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="siema.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**Edit gulpfile.js**

Add the build rule to your gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'css': 'styles.min.css',
        'js': 'script.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

**Run gulp**

As soon as you run `gulp`, the resulting HTML should look like:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing, fits very well into my current process :) thanks

Comment: Very good! If this should be the solution to your problem, please don't forget to select an answer as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use something like [gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml/).  There are others that do the same thing.

```
<!-- build:js js/app.min.js -->
<script src="src/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

During development, you are using the src/js version.  On a build step, you run through a gulp-processhtml step that changes that link to

```
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
```